# Can you get your account suspended for "joking" around?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban, spam, banning

Is it possible that my Stack Overflow account will be suspended for joking around?

**Example:**

> [image]

Can posts like these get me banned?

Comment: Do it often enough maybe. Do you *want* to get suspended? If you really want out, just request deletion.

Comment: Not trying to squelch your enthusiasm,  but you have asked 17 meta questions between MSO and MSE in the last 3 days.  10 have a negative score.  7 have been closed as duplicates (and 1 more has been closed for another reason).  I think you need to resist the urge to click "Ask a question" and just do some research first.  Asking that many questions, especially that are duplicates, is not a good start to getting involved in meta.

Comment: Obvious jwkse% ~hf;wvkj NO CARRIER

Comment: Joking around... yeah right, you were caught out in a lie

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, they can get you suspended; they might not.

It depends on the frequency you post one, the amount of times your comment/post gets flagged, the number of people who find your comment offensive, the moderators mood on the day and the direction the wind is blowing in 1,000km northwest of your current location.

Remember that in order for something to be a "joke" someone else must find it funny...

Comment: My mom thinks I'm hilarious

Comment: I dunno. I've gotten away with [calling 90% of the SO population either a "vampire" or a "whore"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/922184)...

Comment: @Mysticial - That's because (assuming everyone was being honest in that survey) less than 10% of SO users are women.

Comment: @BSMP Why would you think women take more offense than men at being called a vampire?

Answer (score 10):

Well...**yes**.  All actions you do here do have an effect on your ability to participate on the site, regardless of if it was in jest.

The issue here is that I don't *know* if you were joking.  (And if you were, you should knock that off; we're not some run-of-the-mill bulletin board where that behavior is just tolerated.)  If I saw that comment, it'd get flagged, and if you were punished because of it, then so be it - you really shouldn't be joking around like that anyhow.

Keep some professionalism on the site and interact with others as you would if you were doing business with them.  Maintain a level of respect and common courtesy, and things will work out just fine.

Answer (score 6):

As other's mentioned, what's considered a joke or just one of the following flagging choices

[image]

depends. Especially on how often seen from your context, and how frequently your  comments/jokes were flagged for one of the above reasons.

In general keep up a professional tone, listen to (read) what other's are telling you, and don't dress them down with seemingly *joke* comments.

We don't all have broom-sticks in the ass here, and well achieve jokes made in a professional manner (that's nothing contradictorily), but be sure making a joke and make it clear.

You may get banned for such behavior, but not without at least one warning that is sent to you before from a SO moderator.

If you already got one, take it seriously and improve in commenting.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

This is not a joke site, and I imagine the moderators don't take kindly to people consistently wasting the time of others by posting nonsense.

Comment: Upvote for calling it nonsense rather than a joke. SO is not for childish gibberish, try Reddit instead.